# space in php dropdown box variables

Tags: php

I am trying to retrieve data field from a database and store them in a dropdown box so that they correlate to each other which i have done but when I put them into a dropdown box they appear but with no spaces between them and I want the words separated.
Any help much appreciated.

```
<form name="FrmAmend" method="post" action="amenddvd2.php">
Select from the list below<br>
<select name="Film" t[enter link description here][1]itle="Select DVD">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select DVD</option>
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `DVD ID`, `Title`, `Certificate` FROM tbldvd;");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['DVD ID'] . $row['Title'] . $row['Certificate'] . "'>" . $row['DVD ID'] . $row['Title'] . $row['Certificate'] . "</option>";

}
?>
</select><br>
<a href="menu.php"</a>Return To Main Menu<br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Select DVD">
</a>
</form>
```

Comment: So... put spaces between them? `$row['DVD ID'] . " " . $row['Title'] . " " . $row['Certificate']` Is that what you mean?

Comment: Just add space : echo "<option value='" . $row['DVD ID'] . " " . $row['Title'] . " " .$row['Certificate'] . "'>" . $row['DVD ID'] . " " . $row['Title'] . " " .$row['Certificate'] . "</option>";

Comment: You will probably find it better to just use the `$row['DVD ID']` in the `value` attribute. Otherwise when you come to using the value later to refind this row you will have to split the 3 items out into 2 variables, and the DVD_ID I am assuming is the key to this tables rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be better you do it this way

```
    <form name="FrmAmend" method="post" action="amenddvd2.php">
Select from the list below<br>
<select name="Film" t[enter link description here][1]itle="Select DVD">
<option value="" selected disabled>Select DVD</option>
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `DVD ID`, `Title`, `Certificate` FROM tbldvd;");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
    <option value=' <?php echo"$row['DVD ID'] $row['Title'] $row['Certificate']" ?> ' selected disabled>Select DVD</option>
<?php
 }
?>
   </select><br>
<a href="menu.php"</a>Return To Main Menu<br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Select DVD">
</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

concat a space between the vars

```
echo "<option value='" . $row['DVD ID'] . $row['Title'] . $row['Certificate'] . "'>" . $row['DVD ID'] . ' ' . $row['Title'] . ' ' . $row['Certificate'] . "</option>";
```